# Checking Array Key from a JSON decoded array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I am trying to check an array key from a JSON decoded string from my SQL. I am pasting the MySQL field value here directly to avoid long codes.

```
$ajaxcart = "{\"119\":[[\"Front Row\",119,5,3,15]]}";
$cart[] = json_decode(stripslashes($ajaxcart));
foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists(119, $value)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

But don't know why this is returning false always.if I am checking `is_array($value)` it is also returning false.What could be the possible solution?

Comment: json_decode by default returns an object, not an array. You can pass `true` to the second argument to get an array back.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which 119 you want. For the first you want:

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
  if(property_exists($value, '119')){
    echo 'true1';
  }else{
    echo 'false1';
  }
}
```

For the second you need:

```
foreach ($cart[0]->{119} as $key => $value) {
  if(in_array(119, $value)){
    echo 'true2';
  }else{
    echo 'false2';
  }
}
```

You can check it [here](https://3v4l.org/1rKV8)

The reason that you need to iterate over are in part because you don't pass true as a second parameter to json_decode. The second reason is that you use `$cart[] = ...`. This creates an array and adds your decoded json to it. You also have a nested array (`[[`) in your JSON string; this adds another level. Feel free to ask, if I should explain something in more detail.